# Same function with different values to different objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function

i have this function to move my #cubo1 but i want to apply the same function with different values to the others (#cubo2, #cubo3 and #cubo4) however i'm kind of new to this and i have no idea how to do it, i've tried duplicate some parts of the function but every time only one works..

HTML

```
<div class="fundo">
    <div id='cubo1'></div>
    <div id='cubo2'></div>
    <div id='cubo3'></div>
    <div id='cubo4'></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.fundo {
    width: 500px;
    height: 80px;

}

div#cubo1 {
    width: 50px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:red;
    position:fixed;   
}

div#cubo2 {
    width: 50px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:blue;
    position:fixed;   
}

div#cubo3 {
    width: 50px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:green;
    position:fixed;   
}

div#cubo4 {
    width: 50px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:orange;
    position:fixed;   
}
```

JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    animateDiv();   
});

function makeNewPosition(){
    var h = $('.fundo').height() - 50;
    var w = $('.fundo').width() - 50;    
    var nh = Math.floor(Math.random() * h);
    var nw = Math.floor(Math.random() * w);   
    return [nh,nw];     
}
function animateDiv(){
    var newq = makeNewPosition();
    var oldq = $('#cubo1').offset();
    var speed = calcSpeed([oldq.top, oldq.left], newq);
    $('#cubo1').animate({ top: newq[0], left: newq[1] }, speed, function(){
      animateDiv();        
    });    
};




function calcSpeed(prev, next) {   
    var x = Math.abs(prev[1] - next[1]);
    var y = Math.abs(prev[0] - next[0]);    
    var greatest = x > y ? x : y;  
    var speedModifier = 0.01;
    var speed = Math.ceil(greatest/speedModifier);
    return speed;
}

</script>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "every time only one works"?

Comment: everything i tried like copy-paste the "function animateDiv()..." but replacing #cubo1 for #cubo2 and changing some values only one of them would work..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your jQuery selector can be a variable:

```
var i = 1; //or 2 or 3 or 4...

$('#cubo' + i).animate(...);
```

This could also be a parameter to your animateDiv function:

```
function animateDiv(i){
    $('#cubo' + i).animate(...);
}
```

You can stick this in a for-loop if you want to animate all of them:

```
for(var i = 1; i < 5; i++){
   $('#cubo' + i).animate(...);
}
```